# Is there some kind of industry-standard or at least Windows Defender-supported "anti-virus hint config file"?

Tags: anti-virus, windows-10

I have had numerous instances when Windows Defender has just decided to delete **youtube-dl.exe**, located in **My Documents\youtube-dl**.

Similarly, I have a dir where my self-coded e-mail application stores all incoming e-mails' attachments (PNG, JPEG, PDF, etc.). This dir is very likely to contain malware.

I wish I could tell Windows Defender to treat these dirs/files specially. Like, "don't delete this specific file", or "don't delete files in this dir", or "I do not care if you delete the files in this dir, because it's untrusted by me".

I wish this file format is simple and can be easily made into an **AV.conf** or something, and then fed to Windows Defender or other AV software so that they have some idea of what behaviour I want.

And if you think that this could be abused, it would not just accept any changes to this file. I do expect to have to open up the GUI control panel for Windows Defender and tell it to use this specific copy of the file or something like that.

Also, I don't mean that it should ignore all security for the specified dirs. The same runtime protection or whatever would still be in place, only it doesn't flat-out randomly delete files (or spare them) unless it's very sure about what it's doing.

The reason I want this to be a config file of some sort, rather than deal with the GUI control panel, is that I get depressed every time I'm forced to deal with Windows Defender's nonsensical and seemingly unfinished/broken visual "exceptions" and "found threats" and stuff. Basically, my skin starts crawling every time I need to deal with it, which is why I'm trying to minimize any interaction with it due to false positives.

Comment: This is known as an "exception". And Defender already has a way to configure "Allowed Threats" and to define what it scans.

Comment: The capability you want does not exist in Windows Defender. It would be too easy for malware to use such a config to infect your machine. Windows Defender does allow you to exclude a directory from scanning. Put all the files and attachments in this folder.